# Domain has exceeded the max defers and failures per hour - No Cpanel

Tags: email

I am receiving the following error with for most emails that are sent:

```
Domain *** has exceeded the max defers and failures per hour (5/5 (100%)) allowed. Message discarded.
```

I am using PHPMailer to send emails and my software is sending quite a lot of emails per hour.

I have read about changing settings in cpanel to fix this but I do not have cpanel installed on this box.

Is there a way of editing the deferred/failed settings without cpanel?

I am running CentOS 6.4 x32_64 and php v5.3.3

Comment: What control panel if any, and what mail server do you use?

Comment: Are any of your messages from the mailer getting delivered? If not, there may be a problem with the mailer configuration. If some mails are being delivered successfully then there may be an issue with the recipient server. You may be running into their spam filter or the address to which you are sending is not configured properly.